# Force MATLAB to show actual numbers on xlim

Tags: image, matlab, indexing

I have an image in MATLAB that is of size 100 x 200. I have an xAxis that is from -99 to 100. So I show the image like so:

```
mat = randn(100,200);
xAxis = [-99:100];
yAxis = [1:100];
imagesc(xAxis, yAxis, mat);
```

However, I would like the xaxis on the botton to show the ACTUAL number, "-99", and "100". Right now it doesnt show "-99". In some other combinations it might now show either number.

How do I force MATLAB to show the actual numbers being used on the xAxis?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, you can change the ticks in the following way:

```
xTicks = get(gca,'xTick');
xLim = get(gca,'xLim');
xTicksNew = [xLim(1), xTicks];
set(gca,'xTick',xTicksNew);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this line after you call imagesc:

```
set(gca', 'XTickLabel', {'-99', '-80', '-50', '20', '100'}, 'XTick', [-99 -80 -50 20 100]);
```

This will force a label at the points.  The first cell array are the names of the labels, and the vector contains the values at which those labels are placed.

Comment: Oh interesting, cant I just use it for the first and last numbers though, since the middle ones dont give me any issues?

Comment: @mrtubis has a nice way of doing it - I didn't see his answer when I was writing mine.  You can adjust his method by setting xTicksNew = unique([-99 xTicks 100]); and then using the set function.  The unique will insure that you don't have 2 100 values.  This way you don't need to write out all the numbers like I did in the example above.

Comment: if i understand what you are asking, then you can adjust what i suggested before and do `xTicksNew = xLim;`